# Autoconnect bluetooth device on win7 or win10 after system start

Tags: windows-7, windows, bluetooth, connection

Is there any way I can autoconnect my Windows PC (Win7 or Win10) after a system start to my bluetooth speakers?

I am using bluetooth speakers with my PC which is working fine, but after every restart of my PC I have to manually connect to the speakers again. I'm using the CSR Harmony Bluetooth-Software-Stack Version 2.1.63.0 on Win 7.

I want the following behaviour:

1. I start my Windows
2. My bluetooth speakers get automatically connected without clicking any button manually

I'm fine with installing batch script, autohotkey or whatever works.

Comment: Does not seem to be possible automatically>>>>https://superuser.com/questions/1118859/windows-10-reconnect-to-already-paired-bluetooth-device

Comment: thanks for answering, indeed it seems to be not possible per windows default. The referenced post discussed a slightly different topic which is "how to manually connect a paired device", this question is about "how to achieve a reconnect automatically, even with a third party application". Anyone with other suggestions?

Comment: 3rd party software recommendations are off topic here. If you are looking for that, post over here>>>>>>https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thank you! :) posted here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/72609/software-to-autoconnect-bluetooth-device-on-win7-or-win10-after-system-start