# Bluetooth speakers: can't reconnect via action center?

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, speakers

I have a JBL GO 2 bluetooth speaker that is paired to my W10 desktop. They work absolutely fine. Whenever I use this speaker with my phone (or any other device), I need to first manually disconnect from the phone and then on my desktop click the bluetooth icon in the notification tray, click the JBL GO 2 in the list of *Audio* paired devices, and click *Connect*.

[This post](https://superuser.com/a/1195230) showed how you can use the *Connect* tile from the Action Center (<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> for direct access). When I do this, I see other audio devices (*eg* my Plantronics headset and my Jabra earbuds): see [screenshot of Bluetooth audio devices menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qI5MD.png).

However the JBL GO 2 is not in the list, even when it *is* connected: see [screenshot of *Connect* tile content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLrQK.png)

Does anyone have any idea? I'd really like to have a quick way to connect/disconnect from this speaker.

Answer (score 0):

Some general troubleshooting steps for your reference and wish they would be helpful:

**Check if the Bluetooth service is running**

Press Windows Key + R, type services.msc and press Enter.

Search for Bluetooth support service.

Check if it is started, if not Right click on the service and click on Start.

**Restart Bluetooth wireless connectivity**

Search Settings and go to devices--> Bluetooth.

Manually turn the Bluetooth off and On

**Update or reinstall the Bluetooth driver**

Search Device manager and navigate to “Bluetooth” and right-click on the driver.

Perform "update" or "uninstall"

Restart the computer.

**Fix connections to Bluetooth audio devices**

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026226/windows-10-fix-connections-to-bluetooth-audio-wireless-displays

Comment: Thanks @Jenny, but the speakers are connecting and working fine, and show up correctly in the Bluetooth menu. The problem is they don't show up in the _Connect_ tile of the action center, which would allow a quick access to reconnect them when they were previously connected to another device. Bluetooth drivers were already up-to-date.